# How to emit and call an event in c# with reflection?

Tags: c#, events, reflection, emit

I am trying to create an event at runtime with reflection and trying to invoke it before an operation. Something like INotifyPropertyChanged. But i cant invoke my event. I want it to call subscibed methods, in this case Boss1.HeardIt() and print "I Heard you buddy" to screen. What am i doing wrong and how can i do it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOverflowSoru
{
    public delegate void SomeththingHappenedEventHandler();
    public interface Iperson
    {

        void Work(string message);

        event SomeththingHappenedEventHandler SomeththingHappened;
    }
    public class person : Iperson
    {
        public event SomeththingHappenedEventHandler SomeththingHappened;

        public void Work(string thework)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working on: {0}", thework);
        }
    }

    class Boss
    {
        public void HeardIt()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I Heard you buddy");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static Type CreateDynamicProxyType()
        {
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("MyProxies");
            var assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
                   assemblyName,
                   AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            var modBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MyProxies");

            // public class person
            // {
            var typeBuilder = modBuilder.DefineType(
                "mypersonproxy",
                TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class,
                typeof(object),
                new[] { typeof(Iperson) });

            //      private person _realObject;
            var fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField(
                "_realObject",
                typeof(person),
                FieldAttributes.Private);
            //event
            var field = typeBuilder.DefineField("SomeththingHappened", typeof(SomeththingHappenedEventHandler), FieldAttributes.Private);
            var eventInfo = typeBuilder.DefineEvent("SomeththingHappened", EventAttributes.None, typeof(SomeththingHappenedEventHandler));

            //add
            var addMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("add_SomeththingHappened",
        MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.Final | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.NewSlot,
        CallingConventions.Standard | CallingConventions.HasThis,
        typeof(void),
        new[] { typeof(SomeththingHappenedEventHandler)});
            var generator = addMethod.GetILGenerator();
            var combine = typeof(Delegate).GetMethod("Combine", new[] { typeof(Delegate), typeof(Delegate) });
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, combine);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, typeof(SomeththingHappenedEventHandler));
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            eventInfo.SetAddOnMethod(addMethod);

            //remove
            var removeMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("remove_SomeththingHappened",
        MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.Final | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.NewSlot,
        CallingConventions.Standard | CallingConventions.HasThis,
        typeof(void),
        new[] { typeof(SomeththingHappenedEventHandler) });
        var remove = typeof(Delegate).GetMethod("Remove", new[] { typeof(Delegate), typeof(Delegate) });
            var removator = removeMethod.GetILGenerator();
            removator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            removator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            removator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
            removator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            removator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, remove);
            removator.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, typeof(SomeththingHappenedEventHandler));
            removator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
            removator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            eventInfo.SetRemoveOnMethod(removeMethod);

            //      public mypersonproxy(person arg1)
            //      {
            var constructorBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(
                MethodAttributes.Public,
                CallingConventions.HasThis,
                new[] { typeof(person) });
            var contructorIl = constructorBuilder.GetILGenerator();
            contructorIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            contructorIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            contructorIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
            contructorIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            //      }

            //      public void Work(string arg1)
            //      {
            var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Work",
                MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual,
                typeof(void),
                new[] { typeof(string) });
            typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(methodBuilder,
                typeof(Iperson).GetMethod("Work"));
            var tweetIl = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

            //          Console.WriteLine("Hello before!");
            tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello before!");
            tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console)
                .GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] { typeof(string) }));

            //raise probably something wrong here
            var eventmethodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("OnSomeththingHappened",
        MethodAttributes.Family | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.NewSlot,
        typeof(void),
        new[] { typeof(string) });
            var methodgenerator = eventmethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

            var returnLabel = methodgenerator.DefineLabel();

            var eventArgsCtor = typeof(PropertyChangedEventArgs).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });

            methodgenerator.DeclareLocal(typeof(PropertyChangedEventHandler));

            methodgenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            methodgenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field); 
            methodgenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
            methodgenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
            methodgenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse, returnLabel);
            methodgenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
            methodgenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            methodgenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

            methodgenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, eventArgsCtor);
            methodgenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(PropertyChangedEventHandler).GetMethod("Invoke"));
            methodgenerator.MarkLabel(returnLabel);
            methodgenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            eventInfo.SetRaiseMethod(eventmethodBuilder);


            //          _realObject.Work(arg1);
            tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
            tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
                fieldBuilder.FieldType.GetMethod("Work"));

            //          Console.WriteLine("Hello after!");
            tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello after!");
            tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console)
                .GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] { typeof(string) }));
            tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            //      }
            // }


            return typeBuilder.CreateType();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Boss boss1 = new Boss();

            var type = CreateDynamicProxyType();

            var dynamicProxy = (Iperson)Activator.CreateInstance(
                type, new object[] { new person() });

            dynamicProxy.SomeththingHappened += boss1.HeardIt;

            dynamicProxy.Work("fill the excel documents");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to emit the IL for the call to `SomeththingHappened.Invoke()` when generating the Work method on your proxy, you have to add

```
tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(SomeththingHappenedEventHandler).GetMethod("Invoke"));
```

after `tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, fieldBuilder.FieldType.GetMethod("Work"));` (assuming you want the event raised after the call to `_realObject.Work(...)`).

If you want to add the null check to make sure `SomeththingHappened` isn't `null` you can use this version instead

```
Label retLabel = tweetIl.DefineLabel();
tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse_S, retLabel);
tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(SomeththingHappenedEventHandler).GetMethod("Invoke"));

// some other code if you want

tweetIl.MarkLabel(retLabel); //if not null ends here
tweetIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```